# How to styling xml with xslt with looping xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

[image: This what I expect for the output]I have an xml file. The xml file will generate by powershell. The xml file ALWAYS UPDATING. I want to styling the xml file using xslt and make it a simple table.
I tried this, but it still not display a table and the content is not corret yet.

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Tool.xsl"?> 
<report>
    <heading>Image Automation Report</heading>
        <BuildID>1234567</BuildID>
        <que>22</que>
        <pro>2</pro>
        <don>0</don>

        <BuildID>2345678</BuildID>
        <que>21</que>
        <pro>1</pro>
        <don>0</don>
</report>
```

this is my xslt file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="report">
  <table>
    <tr style="background-color:#ccff00">
      <th>BuildID</th>
      <th>que</th>
      <th>pro</th>
      <th>don</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="BuildID">
      <xsl:if test="@type = 'BuildID'">
        <tr style="background-color:#00cc00">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="que"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="pro"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="don"/></td>
       </tr>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "using xslt and make it a simple table. I tried this, but it still not display a table"? Well, what kind of table or result do you want to create, a HTML table? Which tool do you use to try to "display" the table? For a start, if you want to create HTML and don't create a complete HTML document with a proper `html` root element I would strongly suggest to use `<xsl:output method="html"/>`.

Comment: Also how do you load the XML with the `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Tool.xsl"?>` into the tool to display it? From the file system or over HTTP? Unfortunately most browsers these days don't apply XSLT from the file system, due to restricted security settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html" version="1.0" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="report">
        <table>
            <tr style="background-color:#ccff00">
                <th>BuildID</th>
                <th>que</th>
                <th>pro</th>
                <th>don</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="BuildID">

                <tr style="background-color:#00cc00">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::que"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::pro"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::don"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<table>
   <tr style="background-color:#ccff00">
      <th>BuildID</th>
      <th>que</th>
      <th>pro</th>
      <th>don</th>
   </tr>
   <tr style="background-color:#00cc00">
      <td>1234567</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="background-color:#00cc00">
      <td>2345678</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, its not display the table. It just show one line like this `Image Automation Report 1234567 22 2 0 2345678 21 1 0`

Comment: can you share sample output?

Comment: tried it https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output, its generating the output

Comment: check following path and get output

Comment: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=c0c53bf6-fbb0-403d-8f8f-e8c314d47160-xsltransformation

Comment: hi @AjeetSingh I tried it but when I open the xml from browser, it doesnt display the table, its empty just white screen

Answer (score 0):

**You can Try This**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="report"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="report">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <xsl:if test="heading">
                    <tr style="background-color:#9BC2E6">
                        <th colspan="{floor(count(*) div 2)}">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="heading"/>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:if>
                <tr style="background-color:#E2EFDA">
                    <th>BuildID</th>
                    <th>que</th>
                    <th>pro</th>
                    <th>don</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="BuildID">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:attribute name="style">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="(position() mod 2) != 1">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="'background-color:#FFD966'"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="'background-color:#F4B084'"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::que"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::pro"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::don"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: hi @Sandy I tried it but its not working. It doesnt display the table, it just show white screen once I open the file using local browser

Comment: @SBR Please check DEMO: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAy

Comment: it return this `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`
And display this `<report>
<heading>Image Automation Report</heading>
<BuildID>1234567</BuildID>
<que>22</que>
<pro>2</pro>
<don>0</don>
<BuildID>2345678</BuildID>
<que>21</que>
<pro>1</pro>
<don>0</don>
</report>`